# Upload File (.txt .csv ...) to Azure blob [using PowerShell]

Tags: azure, file-upload, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell, azure-sas

Pretty new to Azure... and I have a task to upload a file to a blob using PowerShell.

All the information I got are :

1. **A blob url**       : https://blabla.blob.core.windows.net/whatever
2. **Blob EndPoint**    : https://.........
3. **and a SAS token**  : ?sv=2018-03-28&s.......

I've already connected to my account and got the tenantID but an empty subscription (I thought that I'll have it by default, as the client should add me in there or something like that) which leads to not being able to list the all the storage accounts.

any hints, helps, leads ? or if someone have a better idea or already faced the same situation

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try something like below:

```
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "<account-name>" -SasToken "<sas-token>"
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -File "<full-file-path>" -Container "<container-name>" -Context $ctx
```

You can find more examples of uploading blobs using PowerShell here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/Set-AzStorageBlobContent?view=azps-2.8.0.

Comment: it looks like it's working but when I specify the file path it takes ages to load even thought the file is only 8kb or even empty ? do you maybe have any suggestions or maybe is it something that I forgot to do ?

Comment: That's weird. I just uploaded a file and it was pretty fast. Can you please update your question and include the code you're using?

Comment: You right I missed some inputs from other programs :) , Thanks